# many to many relation between hotels and rooms

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if there is a possibility to create a many to many relation between hotels and rooms.
A hotel has many rooms,but a room doesn't belong to many hotels.
I am new to databases and cant figure it out.

Comment: It's not many to many. A room is only in a single hotel, and a hotel has many rooms, so it's one to many. It is modelled by adding a HotelId field on a room and setting it as a foreign key to the identifier on the hotel table.

Comment: Expand on what you have so far and where you are struggling. Just for the basics: MySQL is a relational database, so of course these kinds of relations are possible. Think of three tables: hotels, rooms and a table that connects both.

Comment: It can't be done. For this reason, hotels and rooms have never been modeled in databases.

Comment: More seriously, as Adrien pointed out, this is a one to many relationship, and would be modeled the same way as any other one-to-many relationship.

Comment: I was thinking the same but that's how my school assignment sounded like(many to many between hotels and rooms).I kind of needed confirmation from more experienced people that its just a one to many relation.Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you had to model it as a many-to-many relationship, you would essentially record only the room number on a room entity. In this manner, a hotel would have many rooms, and a room could exist in many hotels (because lots of hotels have a room numbered 101). This would be a weird way to model hotels and rooms. A lot of room characteristics would then be recorded on the link entity, e.g. `HotelRooms`, such as room type (Single, Double, Twin), which vary across hotels that all had a room with that number.

Comment: Room could also be modelled to define the different types of room available, recording type (single, double, twin, suite...), capacity, facilities, etc. Each hotel would then have a certain number of each type. This may make sense within a hotel chain where each type of room in each hotel is kitted out the same. You would probably call the entity `RoomType`, but it's another option for a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Many to many relationships are done with one table between the two primary tables you want to relate to each other.
One *Hotel* Table, One *Room* Table and between them one table called something like *HotelRoom* (not a perfect naming though).

The joining table *HotelRoom* has fields to each primary key of those tables it joins (In this case *HotelId* and *RoomId*).

So now when you want a single room to be related to several different hotels (or you will come to the conclusion that that is not what you want) you store the primary key to the room and the primary key to the hotel in the *HotelRoom* table.

Then when you want another hotel to be related to that exact room that the other hotel was related to, you store another row in the *HotelRoom* table with the same primary key of the room along with the additional hotel primary key.

This might be what you want, but I suspect that it is not what you want. One scenario I can see would be if you want this to be historical data over what hotels have been owners of this particular room during different times (Far fetched but anyway).

If you just want to surprise and irritate hotel guests, then that would be a hilarious application as well. :)

Comment: I appologize for some not so well chosen language in my first answer. Thank you cf_en for the good point.